# Open ~/.zshrc in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zshrc

Before, I read some articles saying that using command palette and typing `~/.zshrc` somehow can open and edit the file in VS code with highlighting and convenient shortcuts. But now I forget the exact command, and such command seems not working any more. Any thoughts? I don't want to just look at my black terminal and search words line by line.

I've tried looking up this questions but seems no related answers. Change ownership is not the case I want.

Answer (score 0):

Open your home folder and hidden file `.zshrc` would be listed in.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

1. open your terminal
2. make sure you are at your main root directory (outside of any
   projects etc)
3. open in VS Code with the command:

> code .

I'm using a mac. There, in the editor, you should be able to see directories like your desktop, downloads, applications etc. The ~/.zshrc should be visible and after selecting you can make edits